# Waluigi - why does he have a red rose?

Tags: mario-series

What is the reasoning for him having a red rose? We see it in Mario Party 8 (on Wii) and I know I've seen him with some roses in another game... what is his connection with roses?

Comment: I also saw the rose on a Mario Golf game, when he gets an "Eagle" title on a hole.

Comment: Somebody want to explain the downvote? This is a valid question that can be answered, surely? I'm not asking for opinions.

Comment: Questions about [plot and characters](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are valid, yes. Maybe [Tim has lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397) again.

Comment: Can someone get a screenshot of Waluigi with a rose?